# Get Powershell command's output when invoked through code

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I have written a piece of code (in C#) to execute a Powershell script (specifically Azure PowerShell) using `System.Management.Automation`. The powershell script basically uploads a vhd in a container on Azure, which shows the upload progress and time elapsed etc when command is manually entered through azure Powershell. Through code everything works fine but i want to get  the result/output of a command (i.e. upload progress, time elapsed), during command execution (i.e. `pipeline.invoke();`) here is the code:

```
 RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
 runspace.Open();
 RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
 Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

 Command myCommand = new Command(scriptPath);
 foreach (var argument in arguments)
 {
     myCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(argument.Key, argument.Value));
 }
 pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

 var results = pipeline.Invoke(); // i want to get results here (i.e. during command execution) 
 foreach (var psObject in results)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
 }
```

Please guide if it is possible to retrieve live output from Powershell.

Comment: Use the `PowerShell` class instead of `Pipeline`. Then invoke asynchronously and read from `PowerShell.Streams.Progress`

Comment: Can you please guide more using some code?

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: thanks m giving it a try..

Comment: To be clear, with the `DataAdded` eventhandler in place, you don't need to invoke it async. `Invoke()` will do fine

Comment: can't we do it using pipeline? i cant get my script executed when trying using powershell class.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Unless you're targeting PowerShell 1.0, there's no need to set up your runspace and pipeline manually, create an instance of the [`PowerShell` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

```
PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.AddScript(scriptPath);
var results = psinstance.Invoke();
```

Way simpler.

---

Now, the `PowerShell` class exposes the various non-standard output streams (Verbose, Debug, Error etc.) - including the Progress Stream - via the [`Streams` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams(v=vs.85).aspx) so you can subscribe to it, like so:

```
psinstance.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += myProgressEventHandler;
```

And then in your event handler:

```
static void myProgressEventHandler(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressRecord newRecord = ((PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord>)sender)[e.Index];
    if (newRecord.PercentComplete != -1)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Progress updated: {0}", newRecord.PercentComplete);
    }
}
```

---

As an example, here is that event handler shown above in action, while running a sample script that writes progress information (sample script posted below) in a simple console application:

[image: readProgress]

#### Test-Progress.ps1

```
function Test-Progress
{
    param()

    Write-Progress -Activity 'Testing progress' -Status 'Starting' -PercentComplete 0
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 600
    1..10 |ForEach-Object{
        Write-Progress -Activity "Testing progress" -Status 'Progressing' -PercentComplete $(5 + 6.87 * $_)
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400
    }
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Testing progress' -Status 'Ending' -PercentComplete 99
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Testing progress' -Status 'Done' -Completed
}

Test-Progress
```

Comment: Hi, I am using the PowerShell class but the DataAdded event is never triggered for me. My question is why? My code looks like this:

using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShell.AddScript(scriptText); 
    powerShell.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += ProgressDataAdded; 
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke(); 
}

Comment: @IonutEnache Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include the handler code and what you've tried so far :)

Answer (score 6):

It may be a little late, but still.

@Mathias R. Jessen answer works great, but for cases with the output of ordinary strings (without Write-Progress and so on):

Initialize the collection first

```
PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
output.DataAdded += Output_DataAdded;
```

Perform

```
var res = psinstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);
res.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Get the result real-time

```
private static void Output_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    PSObject newRecord = ((PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender)[e.Index];
    Console.WriteLine(newRecord);
}
```

Tested on `Get-Process` PS command.