# ASP.NET C# Output command line since .PS1

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Héllo,

I am trying to see the result of my order from a .PS1 file on a Label in ASP.NET.

Do you have a solution ?
I have tried several methods without success.

CSharp Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;

namespace WebAPPTESTPS1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var SCRIPT_PATH = @"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\WebAPPTESTPS1\WebAPPTESTPS1\test.ps1";
            Process _Proc = new Process();
            _Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "Powershell.exe";
           //_Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            _Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/noexit -executionpolicy bypass -File  " + SCRIPT_PATH + " '" +ServerName.Text + "'";
            _Proc.Start();

            ConfirmationMessage.Text = "The command line " +ServerName.Text + " executed no hidden Window.";
            ServerName.Text = string.Empty;

            _Proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

            _Proc.WaitForExit();
            //StreamReader outputReader = _Proc.StandardOutput;
            //Label1.Text = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
```

I start in programming.
I would like Label1.Text to return the result of the powershell command to me.

Thank you .

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398023/get-powershell-commands-output-when-invoked-through-code

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Not Working

```PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
            psinstance.AddScript(@"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\WebAPPTESTPS1\WebAPPTESTPS1\test.ps1");

var results = psinstance.Invoke(Label1.Text);```