# PowerShell script is NOT displaying any output on the console

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting

I have the below code snippet which runs from a C# file in the backend.

```cs
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    String cmd = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\Demo.ps1";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

    process.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        bool hasExited = process.HasExited;

        String errorStr = null;
        while ((errorStr = process.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
            error.AppendLine(errorStr);

        if (hasExited)
            break;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    if (process.ExitCode != 0 || error.Length > 0)
        throw new Exception(error.ToString());
}
```

Demo.ps1

```
write-host "Working Properly now! "
```

I want the string to be printed in the same PowerShell window which is open, but somehow it's not showing any output to the opened PowerShell window. If I redirect output to a text file then it is clearly visible.

Comment: If you want to run PowerShell code from C#, a better option (especially if you want easy access to the output) is to use the [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0)

Comment: Three bogus answers, with at least one generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)? If that is the case, it is a really sad state of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better approach in my opinion. It is avoiding the hassle of trying to manage by hand the output (std/err).

There is a functionality directly in C#. It is simplifying the interaction and easier for debugging as well.

```
try
{
    ScriptBuilder script = new ScriptBuilder();
    script.LoadScript(File.ReadAllText(@"some.ps1"));
    script.AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"param1", "param1" }
    });
    script.Run();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

This is a simple wrapper used

```
public class ScriptBuilder
{
    private readonly PowerShell powerShellScript;

    public ScriptBuilder()
    {
        powerShellScript = PowerShell.Create();
    }

    public void LoadScript(string script)
    {
        powerShellScript.AddScript(script);
    }

    public void AddParameters(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            powerShellScript.AddParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
        output.DataAdded += Output_DataAdded;

        powerShellScript
            .BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output)
            .AsyncWaitHandle
            .WaitOne();

        powerShellScript.Invoke();
    }

    private static void Output_DataAdded(object? sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        PSObject newRecord = ((PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender)[e.Index];
        Console.WriteLine(newRecord);
    }
}
```

This example is passing arguments to the script and executing the script.

These are some links which could help with further extending the code:

[powershell-host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart)

[system.management.automation.powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell)

[PowerShell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398023/get-powershell-commands-output-when-invoked-through-code)

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for pointing out. I forgot there was a wrapper. It was an old project. Answer updated.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It doesn't seem to be tailored to the question at all.

Comment: @PeterMortensen it shows a better approach. Facilitating the work with the output, replacing the raw string with objects. At least it is an alternative.

Answer (score -2):

The behavior you're observing is because you're running PowerShell as a separate process with different input and output streams, and the output produced by your PowerShell script is not automatically displayed in the parent console window. When you run PowerShell in this way, you need to explicitly handle the redirection of output if you want to see it in the parent console.

Remove the line process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; from your code. This line tells the Process to not redirect the standard output.

Modify your Demo.ps1 script to use the Write-Output cmdlet instead of Write-Host.

```
Write-Output "Working Properly now !"
```

Modified code

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    String cmd = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\Demo.ps1";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

    process.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        bool hasExited = process.HasExited;

        String errorStr = null;
        while ((errorStr = process.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
            error.AppendLine(errorStr);

        if (hasExited)
            break;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    if (process.ExitCode != 0 || error.Length > 0)
        throw new Exception(error.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Somehow this is not working. I think your explanation is correct though. Actually I want to login to another VM from this script. Now in logs it is showing logged in but on console I cannot interact with that VM. How can I open new terminal

Comment: @utkarsh Kendre: It looks like [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) output.